# Git Parallel Builds Merge Conflicts Automatic Resolution

Tags: git, git-merge

We currently in transition to git. We have a parallel build system using GIT as a source control. In general each build agent (Jenkins node), clones the origin, changes the same version file, builds the version, commits the changes, tags the version and pushes the changes (version file and tags) back to the origin. All is done on a single master branch. However I encounter the merging issues.

In the beginning it was (on each node):

1. Clone
2. Change version file
3. Tag
4. Commit file
5. Push <--- This fails because Git says I must pull before, because of changes that were done to the version file by parallel build.

Then I tried to change it to.

1. Clone
2. Change version file
3. Pull <-- This fails because it says it will overwrite the local changes to the version file.

Same happens if the file is committed first.

Goes without saying that it all must be done automatically without human intervention.

UPDATE: I guess what I am trying to find is the pull command which merges the changes automatically in any case. I was trying to do "git pull -s ours origin master". But it didn' work. Still says there are merge conflicts which need to be resolved.

Comment: If the final version file is built from components that *don't* change, so that the version file can be rebuilt in the future from the same inputs, the solution is trivial: never store the final version file. It's just a build artifact. If the final version file *can't* be just a build artifact, you have a problem: it's controlled source and you need to commit the version file first. Then, with the committed version file, *now* you're ready to build. That's a kind of two-stage build. How to do that well in Jenkins, I don't know.

Comment: @torek The file cannot be rebuilt. It is generated automatically during the built it includes timestamp, build number, host etc'. The Jenkins is not the issue. The issue is that several builds in parallel update this file and then try to push the change to git orging. This is cannot be done withour merging the files. What I am trying to figure out is how to so it automatically.

Comment: Then, as I said, you need a two-stage build process. Stage 1 is "build the version file and commit it". This is done *once*, on *one machine*, and results in the final version file. Any new build *completely overwrites* this version file with an all new one, but no re-build of *this* version ever re-does this step at all. Once stage 1 is complete, stage 2—the "main" build—begins and stage 2 can be done as parallel as possible, but it doesn't start until stage 1 has completed by committing the version.

Comment: Since stage 1 is per-build and no stage 2 ever starts before stage 1 completes, there's no such thing as "several builds in parallel". If some other build is proceeding, it has *its own* stages 1 and 2, and it's not on *this* branch at all.